# Problems with saving numbers after formatting example "200,000"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I try to save data from `TextBox1.Text` value to a SQL Server database in column of type `Decimal(18, 0)`. I use VB.NET and SQL Server database.

I format the data in the textbox value to number for example "200,000".

When I try to save, I get this error

> Error converting nvarchar to numeric

I can't use `Val(Textbox1.text)` because he take only "200" not "200000"

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a clear example of why `Val` should never be used.  One of the `Parse` or `TryParse` family will almost always be better.

Answer (score 1):

`18` precision `0` scale is essentially a `Long`, so you should use `Long.Parse()` or `Long.TryParse()` to get the real numeric value in VB. This will give you more control than the antiquated `Val()` over things like separator characters.

Then, in the SQL part, make sure you're using a **parameterized query** with the appropriate type for the parameter:

```
Dim data As Long = Long.Parse(Textbox1.Text)
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [someTable] (column) VALUES (@parameter)"
Using con As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, 0).Value = data
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```